# How to use week in a month seasonality in R Timeseries

Tags: r, forecasting

I am new to R and currently working on `forecast` package. The history dataset I have is having a seasonality effect of weeks in Month i.e. the data is in weekly buckets and the seasonality pattern repeats itself every month.

I understand that time series function for monthly seasonal pattern can be represented as:

```
myts <- ts(data_vector,  start=c(2014,1), end=c(2015,12), frequency = 12)
```

But how should I use timeseries parameters for week in a month seasonality pattern?

P.S. - The resolution could be very simple as I have recently started getting my hands dirty with R.

Comment: Weeks are generally always tricky when it comes to time series, because week count within month or even within year is not consistent. You will run into all sorts of problems with that. For this particular reason I myself have always avoided weekly measures, hence can not add much more to this.

Comment: Changing frequency to month could be an easy way out but the forecasting process has been well established and is being done in excel right now, so would need to find an appropriate way out.

Comment: Well, in this case - I don't think that `ts` frequency needs to be an integer. Try using: 365.25 / 7 = 52.17857 as frequency. This should be a reasonable average. Although - I have never experimented what effects can it yield.

Comment: I think if we use ~52 as frequency, ts() will treat this seasonality as weekly and while using with ets() or forecast(), it would be treated as Week on week seasonality in year rather than month, i.e. W1 will follow the pattern exhibited in W53. What I need is, that W1 should follow the pattern as in W5 and so on.